# Recommend deletion "This should be a comment" flag not available, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12365217) low quality post (from 2015), the answer should clearly be a comment:

> So which version of java are you using to run this program?

But I think because the question is so old: `answered Nov 10 '15 at 15:16`, there is only the "This is a link-only answer (and not spam)" option available.

Should I add a comment, and recommend deletion with no comments? Or what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an answer to the question and is therefore subject to deletion, which is exactly what has now happened to it.

You could add a comment to the question yourself that the OP was using java 8 if you really thought it would help get answers to the question.

Comment: OK, I'll think about it. So it was an audit, right?

Comment: No, it wasn't an audit.

Comment: but if it is already deleted, my actions don't matter anymore

Comment: Oh wait, others did it, nevermind. Thanks

Comment: I really wish that the flag description was a bit better.  Every time I use it, I feel uncertain, especially with link only answers.